# Creating constant objects in C# EF CodeFirst?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a class "Stage" that contains an Id, Name, and TimeSpan.  I need to create some constant Stages that can be referenced throughout my entire application.  The Stage table and Stages should be read-only once these constants are defined.

The Stage class:

```
public class Stage
{
    [Key]
    public virtual int StageId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan Span { get; set; }
}
```

I've tried the following (defining two constants):

```
public class Stage
{
    [Key]
    public virtual int StageId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan Span { get; set; }

    public static class Values
    {
        public static readonly Stage ONE = new Stage()
            {
                StageId = 0,
                Name = "ONE",
                Span = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0)
            };
        public static readonly Stage TWO = new Stage()
        {
            StageId = 1,
            Name = "TWO",
            Span = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10)
        };
}
```

But whenever I create a new instance of an entity that has a Stage, a new Stage is added to the db.  I just need a few constant stages.

Related entity constructor that's creating new instances when it should just be a reference to an existing stage (as defined above):

```
public class Side
{
    public Side()
    {
        Stage = Stage.Values.ONE;
    }
    public virtual Stage Stage { get; set; }
}
```

**How can I create a handful of constant objects and reference them via `Stage.Values.One` syntax?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must attach `Stage.Values.ONE` and `Stage.Values.TWO` to the context instances where you are working with entities that reference those two constant entities in order to prevent that new `Stage` objects are created in the database, like

```
context.Stages.Attach(Stage.Values.ONE)
```

I would prefer though to have "context-local" constant entities instead of global static objects to avoid possible problems that can occur when they are attached to two different context instances at the same time. Something like:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    //...
    public Stage StageONE
    {
        get
        {
            var stage = this.Stages.Local.SingleOrDefault(s => s.StageId == 0);
            if (stage == null)
            {
                stage = new Stage()
                {
                    StageId = stageId,
                    Name = "ONE",
                    Span = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0)
                };
                this.Stages.Attach(stage)
            }
            return stage;
        }
    }
}
```

To be used like so:

```
using (var context = new MyContext())
{
    var side = new Side { Stage = context.StageONE };
    context.Sides.Add(side);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

But it doesn't seem to make much sense to me to store something in the database that you never read from there and only use hard-coded in your application. You could just make  `Side.Stage` a `byte` property and use `0` and `1` for it.

Comment: "You could just make Side.Stage a byte property and use 0 and 1 for it." - say I have ten stages.  How could this approach be used?  Also - what is the "standard" approach to this?  Requiring some constants *has* to be a common scenario, right?

Comment: @SB2055: For ten fixed stages you could use an `enum` (EF 5 supports that). I don't know if the scenario is common, I never had the need for such constants in the DB. I had tables that are "almost" constant (for example a table with countries) and very unlikely to change, but I still read them from the DB (with `Find`). To reduce the number of reads and to improve performance caching might be an option, i.e. read only once (or only once every hour with an expiring cache) and then access only the cache. But I'd think about such complications only if there is a *proven* performance bottleneck.